# C# program issues.....Error 12 Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct and others

Tags: c#, sql, error-handling, enums

I am writing an ATM application for my C# class. It gets its information from a database online. I keep getting several errors, but the one I am trying to figure out is the Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct error. Here is the code any ideas?

```
namespace ATMapp
{


public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
             // instance variables used to manipulate database

        private Connection myConnection;
        private Statement myStatement;
        private ResultSet myResultSet;
        string databaseURL = "http://www.boehnecamp.com/phpMyAdmin/razorsql_mysql_bridge.php";
        // establish connection to database

        try
         {

    // connect to database
            SQL sql = new SQL();
            myConnection = sql.getConnection(databaseURL);

    // create Statement for executing SQL
            myStatement = myConnection.createStatement(databaseURL);
         }
         catch (Exception)
              { 
               Console.WriteLine ("Cannot connect to database server");
              } 
    // close statement and database connection
         myStatement.close();
         myConnection.close();

     // load account numbers to accountNumberJComboBox

    private void loadAccountNumbers()
      {
      // get all account numbers from database
         try 
         {
            myResultSet = myStatement.executeQuery("SELECT accountNumber FROM accountInformation");

         // add account numbers to accountNumberJComboBox
            while ( myResultSet.next() )
            {
               accountComboBox = accountNumberComboBox.Item.Add(myResultSet.getString( "accountNumber" ) );
               //ComboBox accountNumberComboBox = new ComboBox();
            }

            myResultSet.close(); // close myResultSet

         } // end try

             catch ( Exception)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Error in loadAccountNumbers");
            }

      } // end method loadAccountNumbers

    private void retrieveAccountInformation()
      {
      // get account information
         try 
         {
            myResultSet = myStatement.executeQuery( "SELECT pin, " + 
               "firstName, balanceAmount FROM accountInformation " +
               "WHERE accountNumber = '" + userAccountNumber + "'" );

         // get next result
            if ( myResultSet.next() )
            {
               pin = myResultSet.getString( "pin" );
               firstName = myResultSet.getString( "firstName" );
               balance = myResultSet.getDouble( "balanceAmount" );
            }

            myResultSet.close(); // close myResultSet

         } // end try

             catch (Exception)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Error in retrieveAccountInformation");
            }

      } // end method retrieveAccountInformation
// update database after withdrawing

    private void updateBalance()
      {
      // update balance in database
         try
         {
            myStatement.executeUpdate( "UPDATE accountInformation" +
               " SET balanceAmount = " + balance + " WHERE " +
               "accountNumber = '" + userAccountNumber + "'" );
         }
             catch (Exception)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Error in updateBalance");
            }

      } // end method updateBalance
```

Comment: It would help if you could tell just the exact line the error occurs on.

Comment: The issue is that you are putting code just into the body of the class, and not in a method.

Comment: As @Siyual says. You need to put the code from //establish connection to database    to just before //load account numbers to accountNumberJComboBox into a method.